# AutoMapper Map entity with self-reference entity

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have a small problem that gives me a StackOweflow problem.

I use EF 4.1 with complextypes and this works, the problem is that you need to create an instance of the complextype even if all the values are null, to make it work with EF.

So now I have a class that looks like this..

```
public class GoodsItem{

  public GoodsItem InnerGoodsItem{get;set;}

  //-- A lot of other properties needed for this class

  public GoodsItem()
  {
     this.InnerGoodsItem = new GoodsItem();
  }
}
```

I need the code in the constructor for EF to work as it should, but then every time I create a GoodsItem it creates a new GoodItems that creates a new GoodsItem and so on...

How can I solve this problem with AutoMapper and still keep EF 4.1 happy.

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

Can't see how that constructor could ever work.  Perhaps you could change your class to initialize the inner item in the property get, like this:

```
public class GoodsItem{

    private GoodsItem _innerGoodsItem;
    public GoodsItem InnerGoodsItem
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_innerGoodsItem == null) _innerGoodsItem = new GoodsItem();
            return _innerGoodsItem;
        }
        set { _innerGoodsItem = value; }
    }

    //-- A lot of other properties needed for this class

    public GoodsItem()
    {
       //No longer need this call in ctor
       //this.InnerGoodsItem = new GoodsItem();
    }
}
```

Not sure if this will cause a problem with EF though (thankfully, I've pretty much avoided EF so far!).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I took the easy way out and made the InnerGoods a collection of GoodsItem. And the problem was solved. And that solution was actually more correct when we have spooken to the businesspeople about it...

Comment: Well, as long as the business is happy! Feel free to upvote ;-)